# Is it possible to use interpolation in YAML translation keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, interpolation

Say I have two yaml keys in a I18n file:

```
level1:
  level2:
    foo: 'Something'
    bar: 'Something else'
```

I would reference these key like so: `t('level1.level2.foo')` and `t('level1.level2.bar')`. If I have a variable `var`, the type of which returns either `'foo'` or `'bar'`, could I do something like: `t('level1.level2.#{var.type}')`. And now the even trickier part - what if I already use the key inside string interpolation like:

```
"The type of the #{var.to_s} variable is #{t('level1.level2.#{var.type}')}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it works, except for interpolation to be applied, you need to use double quotes, not single:

```
t("level1.level2.#{var.type}")
"The type of the #{var.to_s} variable is #{t("level1.level2.#{var.type}")}"
```

Example:

```
[1] pry(main)> var = OpenStruct.new
=> #<OpenStruct>
[2] pry(main)> var.type = 'foo'
=> "foo"
[3] pry(main)> "The type of the #{var.to_s} variable is #{I18n.t("level1.level2.#{var.type}")}"
=> "The type of the #<OpenStruct type=\"foo\"> variable is translation missing: en.level1.level2.foo"
```

Comment: Well that's the thing - I want to use intepolation in the YAML keys, not the YAML values.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't try it beforehand, I was almost sure, that #{} within #{} wouldn't work. Thank you :)